# Split a string in java based on custom logic

Tags: java

I have a string

```
"target/abcd12345671.csv"
```

and I need to extract

```
"abcd12345671"
```

from the string using Java. Can anyone suggest me a clean way to extract this.

Comment: split at `/` and `.`!?

Comment: [Path.getFileName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Core Java**

```
String fileName = Paths.get("target/abcd12345671.csv").getFileName().toString();
fileName = filename.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "")
```

Using **apache commons**

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
String fileName = Paths.get("target/abcd12345671.csv").getFileName().toString();
String fileNameWithoutExt = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like a regex replace approach here:

```java
String filename = "target/abcd12345671.csv";
String output = filename.replaceAll("^.*/|\\..*$", "");
System.out.println(output);  // abcd12345671
```

Here we use a regex alternation to remove all content up, and including, the final forward slash, as well as all content from the dot in the extension to the end of the filename.  This leaves behind the content you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with using regex

```
String filename = "target/abcd12345671.csv";

var pattern = Pattern.compile("target/(.*).csv");
var matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // Whole matched expression -> "target/abcd12345671.csv"
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    // Matched in the first group -> in regex it is the (.*) expression
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```